Дана некоторая строка. Найдите позицию третьего нуля в строке
Есть вопрос по задаче.
Нужно найти позицию третьего нуля в строке.
Сам ничего не придумал, в интернете тоже ничего не нашёл.
Вот пример кода для поиска первого нуля в строке
def find_zero(s):
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == '0':
            return index
    return "Нулей нет"

print(find_zero("abc0def"))
print(find_zero("abcdef"))

Подскажите на его основе как написать код для позиции третьего нуля.

Подскажу - нужно считать встретившиеся нули.

Первый шаг - split по '0'

А как ты вручную ищешь третий нуль в строке?

def find_zero(s):
    c = 0
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == '0':
            c += 1
            if c == 3:
                return index
    return "Трёх нулей нет"


print(find_zero("abc0def"))
print(find_zero("abcdef"))
print(find_zero("ab00cd0ef"))



Трёх нулей нет
Трёх нулей нет
6


В первом примере нули есть! В третьем примере позиция третьего нуля не 6!

Индекс 6, если нужно по счету с 1 сделай return index + 1, третьих нулей нет и не вижу в задании что писать если нулей меньше 3

В при мере в вопросе функция кстати тоже возвращает индекс

@Эникейщик почему позиция не 6? База ведь взята из вопроса

@0xdb почему предлагается удалить этот ответ?

Решение в одну строку:
vvar = input("Введите строку: ")
print("Позиция третьего нуля в строке: %s" % [index for index, value in
    enumerate(vvar) if value == "0"][2:3] if len([index for index, value in 
    enumerate(vvar) if value == "0"]) >= 3 else "Нет трёх нулей!")


Достаточно разделить строку на символы и искать символы соответствующие нулю, а затем считать количество встретившихся нулей.
def position_3_zero(str):

    count = 0
    for index, symbol in enumerate(str.strip()):
        if symbol == '0':
            count += 1
            if count == 3:
                pos = index
    return pos


if __name__ == "__main__":

    str_list = ["abcj0ajf0ajb0",
                "jddi0wejfn00",
                "000aknfakfn",
                "aknfa000ajfnajfn"]

    for str in str_list:
        pos = position_3_zero(str)
        print(pos)

12
11
2
7

Зачем strip()?  В задании ничего не сказано, что нужно удалять какие-то символы. И такая же проблема, как в другом ответе — выдает неправильный номер. И к тому же крашится, если в строке меньше трёх нулей.

Формулировки задания вообще нет. Вы предоставили задачу, но как её решать не указали, это Ваша проблема.
Функция выдает позицию (индекс) третьего нуля, что в Вашем примере собственно и происходит, если Вам нужен номер, укажите это в формулировке задания, которой у Вас нет.
В задаче просят написать функцию для нахождения позиции третьего нуля и ничего не сказано про альтернативные случаи. Доработайте код, StackOverflow задумывался как форум для поиска вдохновения и решения сложных вопросов, а не готовых решений для Ваших контрольных работ.
